# Add class to element in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this string

```
var string = 'this is a string <a href="/bar">this is a element</a>';
```

How can I add a class **foo** to de element `<a>`, then make it a string again? Like this

```
'this is a string <a href="/bar" class="foo">this is a element</a>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create DOM element using the HTML string, manipulate and get the required string.

```js
var str = 'this is a string <a href="/bar">this is a element</a>'
str = $('<div></div>').html(str).find('a').addClass('myClass').end().html();
alert(str)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

if you use jquery 
you can use 'addClass'

```
js
$("a").addClass("foo");
```